# React JSX: If else with component properties

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have seen this  code snippet in a book and I cant compile the following code.

```js
    var TaskItem = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var task = this.props.task;

        return (
          <li>
            <span>{task.name}</span>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox"

                   if (task.completed) {checked = "checked";} else { checked =  "";
    }
                onChange={this.props.markTaskComplete}

              <button onClick={this.props.removeTask}>Remove</button>
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      }
    });
```

Getting this as error :

> Failed to compile. ./src/index.js Syntax error:
>   D:/Users/rajeevakotkar/Documents/node/my-app/src/index.js: Unexpec ted
>   token (20:18) 18 |  20 | if
>   (task.completed) {checked = "checked";} else { checked = ""; | ^ 21 |
>   } 22 | onChange={this.props.markTaskComplete 23 |

I have tried few links from stackoverflow, but didnt help.My apologies for asking too naive question.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed closing bracket for

```
onChange={this.props.markTaskComplete
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic if/else is not allowed in the return statement.
There are a lot of solutions for this:

**First:**
What you could do is use the following syntax:

```
checked={task.completed ? "checked" : "" }
```

**Second:** If you want to do something more complex you can create a variable before the return and output it in the render like this:

```
 render(){
    let checked = "";
    if(task.completed){
       checked="checked";
    }
    return(... checked={checked}...);
    }
```

**Third:** you could call another function to calculate the value:

```
    dosth(){
        return task.completed ? "checked" : "";
    }
    render(){
        return(... 
            checked={this.dosth()} 
            ...);
    }
```

you can read more about this here: [React Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: Is the above your full code? You need to define somewhere what a task actually is, in your case you have to pass the value of that definiton in the parameter, task={valueOfYourTask}, when you use your TaskItem component. I don't see any errors in particular in the code you posted, else from what i already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `task.completed` is a boolean just assign the value to the `checked` attribute.

```
var TaskItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var task = this.props.task;

    return (
      <li>
        <span>{task.name}</span>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox"
            checked={task.completed} // this line
            onChange={this.props.markTaskComplete}

          <button onClick={this.props.removeTask}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```